# Objective C categories

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes , Lets say ClassA and ClassB , ClassB is a subclass of ClassA .

And I am adding a Category to the ClassA ,

```
@interface ClassA (DataHandling)
-(void)addData;
@end
```

Then to the sublcass I add a another category ,

```
@interface ClassB (DataHandling)
-(void)addDataGlobally;
@end
```

Will this be treated as a single category on multiple categories and will I run in to any conflicts, though the method names are different  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different categories on two different classes.

No conflicts will take place, however it's considered a best practice to prefix the category methods with a unique identifier, something like

```
-(void)my_addDataGlobally;
```